# Angular2 service method add new item from input

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a method to create a new Player. But when i write something in input and submit my app do nothing (just refresh page).

Here is my code:

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from './player';
import { WhitePlayers } from './mock-players';

@Injectable()
export class PlayersService {
  WhitePlayers: Player[];
  name;
  constructor() { }
    getPlayers(): Promise<Player[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(WhitePlayers);
    }

  createPlayer(): void {
    this.WhitePlayers.push(new Player(this.name));
  }

}
```

component.ts

```
addPlayer(): void {
      this.playersServices.createPlayer();
    }
```

component.html

```
<form (submit)="addPlayer()" novalidate>
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="Add player" name="addNewPlayer">
    </md-input-container>
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Thank you very much for the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page is refreshed your values in the field will be initialized again.

you can change the button type to `button` to avoid this.

```
<button type="button">Add</button>
```

---

You should also check the forms documentation. You can bind the form to a model and use `ngSubmit` to have a more Angular way in this process.

https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit